# Comparing strings

Tags: php, string, comparison

```
<?php
    $string1 = "12 jan";
    $string2 = "12 aprail, 13 march";
    $result = strcmp($string1, $string2);

    switch ($result) {
        case -1: print "date are not identical"; break;
        case 0: print "date1"; break;
        case 1: print "date are identical"; break;
    }
?>
```

when i use this code it will show me a date are identical even the value ex
when i compare the value 12 jan to 12 march
it will show me value are identical
but the value is differ

Answer (score 6):

You have used the wrong return values.

- `-1` and `1` mean that the strings are not identical (less than and greater than, respectively).
- `0` means that the strings are identical.

Answer (score 1):

The function [**strcmp**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) returns

```
< 0 if str1 is less than str2; 
> 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 
0 if they are equal.
```

Answer (score 1):

strcmp "returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal". You're printing "date are identical" when $result == 1, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

strcmp returns:

- a negative number if string1 is less
  than string2
- zero if the two strings
  are equal
- a positive number of
  string1 is greater than string2

It is incorrect to assume that strcmp will return only -1, 0, or 1.